# Strange behavior of click event and event propagation bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-propagation

Suppose this UI:

```
<div id="wpforms-1345-field_6-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-radio row-selection" data-field-id="6">
  <label class="wpforms-field-label" for="wpforms-1345-field_6">What is your age?
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span>
  </label>
  <ul id="wpforms-1345-field_6" class="wpforms-field-required">
    <li class="choice-1 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_1" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="0-15" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_1">0-15</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-2 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_2" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="16-25" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_2">16-25</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-3 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_3" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="26-35" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_3">26-35</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-5 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_5" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="36-45" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_5">36-45</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-4 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_4" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="46-100" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_4">≥46</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want is to be able to select a radio `input` by clicking on the parent `li`. Unfortunately the interface is not built by me, so I can't set the `for` attributes appropriately (put them in the `li`s, instead of in the `label`s).

Therefore my only resource is JS (JQ actually)... So I wrote this small snippet to deal with the situation:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.row-selection li').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked');
    //   event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('input')[0].click(function(event) {
      alert('bubbledup');
      //    event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
});
```

But notice the alerts? Well, the problem is that each "clicked" alert hits twice... At first, I thought that some bubbling up was occurring. But after putting the appropriate code in place (`event.stopPropagation();`) I still get double "clicked" `alert`s, and no "bubbledup" `alert`s.

So basically it works fine and I get the effect I need, I just don't understand why I get the double `alert`s. What am I missing here?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/princeofabyss/p1uh2dzy/) is a small fiddle I created to help you help me more easily. In the fiddle I also put some additional JS code that adds a couple of classes in order to achieve the coloring of the `li`s according to my needs. TIA

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure why you're putting an event listener in an event listener. Try removing the callback from the children `.click(...)` function call; that'll actually click the button instead of waiting for an additional click.

Comment: @code it still does it... Just refresh the fiddle and see!

Comment: I know, but that gets rid of half the problem.

Comment: What about the other half? Can you help me please?

Comment: I just got it. It fires twice because the inner click causes a bubble, so it alerts twice. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I know it causes a bubble, but that's exactly why I put the inner listener, to be able to stop the bubbling by using the inner `event.stopPropagation();` but for some strange reason it didn't work...

Comment: You have to put it _outside_ the `li` event listener, or it will only start listening after the first `li` click.

Comment: Probably not edit the question. Either ask a new one, or we could privately chat in the SO chat and I could give it a look.

Comment: I've never used that chat! Can you send me an invitation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248668/discussion-between-code-and-faye-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you click on the `li` element, the `li` element clicks the `input` element. When the `input` element is clicked, the event bubbles and makes the `li` element think it’s clicked again. This can even happen three times when you click on the `input` itself, which fires the `li` event listener, which clicks the `input` which triggers the `li` event listener.

You can solve this by creating a listener and stopping propagation for the radio button **outside** the `li` event listener (you were close):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let t = 0;
  $('.row-selection li').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log("fired", ++t, "times")
    $(this).children('input')[0].click();
  });
  // right HERE!! 
  $('.row-selection li input').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });



  $(document).on('change', '.wpforms-field-checkbox input, .wpforms-field-radio input, .wpforms-field-payment-multiple input, .wpforms-field-payment-checkbox input, .wpforms-field-gdpr-checkbox input', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $field = $this.closest('.wpforms-field');

    switch ($this.attr('type')) {
      case 'radio':
        $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('wpforms-selected').find('input[type=radio]').removeProp('checked');
        $this.prop('checked', true).closest('li').addClass('wpforms-selected');
        break;
      case 'checkbox':
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
          $this.closest('li').addClass('wpforms-selected');
          $this.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
          $this.closest('li').removeClass('wpforms-selected');
          $this.prop('checked', false);
        }
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #eef5fa !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px !important;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

ul li.wpforms-selected {
  background-color: #cee1f2 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wpforms-1345-field_6-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-radio row-selection" data-field-id="6">
  <label class="wpforms-field-label" for="wpforms-1345-field_6">What is your age?
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span>
  </label>
  <ul id="wpforms-1345-field_6" class="wpforms-field-required">
    <li class="choice-1 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_1" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="0-15" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_1">0-15</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-2 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_2" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="16-25" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_2">16-25</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-3 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_3" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="26-35" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_3">26-35</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-5 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_5" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="36-45" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_5">36-45</label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice-4 depth-1">
      <input type="radio" id="wpforms-1345-field_6_4" name="wpforms[fields][6]" value="46-100" required="">
      <label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1345-field_6_4">≥46</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG this worked like a charm! And you helped me in 5 minutes while I spent 2 hours of my life trying to figure it out... Thank you so very much!

Comment: @FayeD. glad it helped. You were actually pretty close.

Comment: I know, but I didn't know/would never have thought to put the listener outside the, so no matter how close I was, I'd never be able to figure that out myself... :(